# Python login to website requiring MFA token

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, automation

I am attempting to create a login tool for my work which will log me in to various sites that log me out after 3 minutes of inactivity. I have gotten it to work on a number of sites, but none have required an MFA token. I currently use Google Authenticator but can also use an email, or a couple different options. How would I go about getting that code programmatically to make my login process much faster? I am using Selenium as I need to use the webpage after I log into it. Here is my code thus far:

```
def loginsys():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.specifiedurl.com/login')
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('txtUsername')
    password = driver.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
    username.send_keys("myusername")
    password.send_keys("mypassword")
    driver.find_element_by_name('btnLogin').click() 
    ### This is where I need to do MFA as it will not pull the next page without it
    driver.get('https://www.specifiedurl.com/page/after/login')
```

Thoughts? (Obviously, this is not the url, nor is that my actual username or password)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `pyotp` library. You can get the MFA key associated with google authentication as shown below.

```
from pyotp import *

# get the token from google authentication 
totp = TOTP("your 16 character security token goes here")
token = totp.now()
print (token)
# now you can use token in your script
```